# Sql Server - Running a Job on Multiple servers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SqlServer 2008.

I have a Sql Server Job that checks Disk Space and emails admins if the space is less than 15%

Instead of adding that Job to all servers is it Possible to run the Job on all servers ?

(I have those servers added as Linked Servers)

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server to check disk space? Wrong tool for the job. Try PowerShell.

Comment: Hi Aaron - Thank you. I will look at that option. But they had this set up on all the servers. I need to find a way to make all Jobs work from one central location.

Comment: Powershell does not exist on older version of SQL Server.  Sometimes the wrong tool is the only tool.

Comment: @datagod the beauty of PowerShell is it's decoupled from SQL Server. Version of SQL Server is irrelevant because the script could be automated from any server, not just one that has SQL Server on it. To be clear, I'm not talking about running a PowerShell job step from SQL Server Agent, but an actual PowerShell script.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I guess I was thinking more of querying WMI from powershell.  WMI does not exist on Windows 2000/2003 servers.  Sadly, there are still a few of those kicking around.

Comment: @datagod we use the Win32APIs and they work just fine. You can't possibly tell me that there's no way to get disk space info from a 2000/2003 server unless you use xp_cmdshell. Plus, whatever xp_cmdshell is doing on that box you could execute remotely via PowerShell. Finally, the OP didn't say they were saddled with servers that old and unsupported...

Comment: @datagod I also think maybe there's some confusion about where I'm suggesting this be run. I'm not saying every server should have a PowerShell script locally. You can have PowerShell on one central server polling info from WMI/WMIC or Win32 APIs across a variety of servers, whether they're running PowerShell, SQL Server etc. or not.

Comment: @datagod Finally, I'm not sure what parts of WMI you don't think are available in Windows Server 2000 or later. [This article seems to disagree](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) (see Q2), and I seem to remember first playing with it back around that timeframe too.

Comment: @aaronBertrand, why are you mentioning xp_cmdshell??

Comment: @datagod well how else do you advocate they get drive space from SQL Server? Undocumented, unsupported `xp_fixeddrives`, which won't get all volume types? `dm_os_volume_stats`, which only exists on modern versions of SQL Server and only returns information for drives that house at least one data or log file? Look, you shot down my suggestion of PowerShell because you claimed WMI doesn't exist on these older servers - which isn't true *even if the OP had mentioned that support was necessary*. If you have a better answer, please provide one instead of nit-picking my comments.

Comment: @aaronBertrand, I get your point.  There is no need to berate with me multiple comments.  The environment I was supporting was a mixed bag.  I could not get the powershell query (running on one central machine) to talk nicely with the windows 2000 box.  I tried everything, but in the end gave up.  So it exists, you are correct.  And that was several years ago, so perhaps my memory is not what it used to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the specific question of running a SQL Agent job on multiple servers (definitely a good question) and, for the moment, ignoring the particular thing that you want the job to do (which could be another question):

SQL Server / SQL Server Agent actually comes with a facility that makes this type of thing *very* easy: **multiserver administration**. You set up a Master (MSX) and several Target (TSX) servers. You then create the job only on the Master and then select which of the Target servers it should run on.

Please see the section of MSDN pages, starting with [Automated Administration Across an Enterprise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180992.aspx).

It is actually quite nice. I worked at a place with 50 (at least) instances in Product, plus 5 other environments (Dev, QA, etc) with something like 12 - 30 instance per environment. Lots of SQL Agent jobs, mostly managed via MSX / TSX.

You can still create jobs local to any particular instance. For example, when migrating data from a large table to a new structure (a pre-release task for minimizing downtime so that during the release the tables just need to be swapped), about 1 week prior to the release I would create the new tables and local jobs to migrate batches of 1k - 4k rows, every few minutes. Creating them as local instead of MSX allowed for:

- *Setting different batch sizes and schedules per node*: We had 20 nodes and some were either quite a bit larger than the rest or maybe quite a bit smaller. Different batch sizes worked better for different data volumes. Along those same lines, as the jobs working on the nodes with larger tables got to maybe 30% complete or something, they started to slow down, requiring minor changes to batch size and/or schedule frequency. It is not possible with MSX (without a large `CASE @@SERVERNAME` statement) to tailor job specifics per Target / TSX server.
- *Auto-clean up*: The very nature of these jobs was temporary, and once all of the data on a node had been migrated, there was no more purpose in that partcular job as new rows can be handled via the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE trigger that kept the already migrated rows in sync. Hence, once the job detected that 0 rows were moved, it looked up its own `JobID` and called `[msdb].dbo.sp_delete_job` to delete itself. Doing this meant that we didn't have jobs running that weren't doing any work, and we didn't have to worry about job cleanup during or after the release. I do not think this is possible with MSX / TSX as I do not think a TSX server can delist one of its MSX jobs. Of course, the documentation for [sp_delete_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) doesn't say that it *can't* and I haven't tried.

And Linked Servers aren't required for any of the MSX / TSX communication. In fact, you should be careful when restoring a backup of an MSX server to another server for the purposes of testing. I did that one time with our Product MSX server and started removing some of the Target server meta-data as it was cluttering up what I was trying to test. A few hours later the lead DBA sent out an urgent message asking who was messing with the Jobs in Production as quite a few jobs were being mysteriously delisted from some / most / all of their TSX servers. I just happened to be that the server I was using for testing was sitting inside the Production network for obsolete technical reasons and was allowed to communicate with the TSX nodes. Oops ;-). Needless to say, Mr Lead DBA was something quite-the-opposite-of-happy with me (and the junior DBA who did the restore for me).

To be clear about the behavior, when you select a Target server, the job and its related data (steps, schedule(s), etc) are replicated to that TSX server. So the job will live on the Target server and run via SQL Agent *on that Target server*; the jobs are *not* running on the Master server.

If you have ever wondered what the `[originating_server_id]` field was in `[msdb].dbo.sysjobs`, it refers to the Master/MSX server (I believe a value of `0` means a "local" job).

```
SELECT * FROM [msdb].dbo.sysjobs -- originating_server_id
```

Also:

```
-- map of jobs and what Target/TSX servers they are on
SELECT * FROM [msdb].dbo.sysjobservers 

-- registered TSX servers
SELECT * FROM [msdb].dbo.systargetservers
```

Here is the full list of [SQL Server Agent Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181367.aspx)